# How to display an element with multiple value options?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the hidden div when user choose any option from the `<optgroup>` 
my code is working but for only one option i want to make it work for all options in specific `<optgroup>`.

> I don't want to use array because I will edit the JS array every time adding option in this specific optgroup.

```js
function show(that) {
    if (that.value == "show1") {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="show(this);">
    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
    <optgroup label="show div">
    <option value="show1">show 1</option>
    <option value="show2">show 2</option>
    <option value="show3">show 3</option>
    </optgroup>
   <!-- i don't want it work with this another optgroup -->
   <optgroup label="another">
    <option value="useless">useless</option>
    <option value="useless2">useless</option>
    <option value="useless4">useless</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    Hidden Div
</div>
```

Comment: An answer has already been given below, but since you were only comparing `value` to one particular value, `"show1"` in the first place, what else would you expect but for it to only work for that one value?

You either have to compare to all of the values you want the item hidden for, all of them you don't want it hidden for, or to some pattern (like `value.startsWith('show')` that matches what you want.

Comment: @kshetline it's a good solution startWith but the values are not similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `optgroup` and check if that's the one you want:

```js
function show(that) {
  let selected_option = that.options[that.selectedIndex];
  let optgroup = selected_option.parentNode;
  if (optgroup.label == 'show div') {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="show(this);">
  <option value="" selected>choose</option>
  <optgroup label="show div">
    <option value="show1">show 1</option>
    <option value="show2">show 2</option>
    <option value="show3">show 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
  Hidden Div
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you perfect answer with pure js :)

Answer (score 0):

In your show() method,  change if(that.value == “show1”) to  if(that.value !== “”)

That way,  if you have nothing selected,  the div will not be shown,  otherwise,  it will.

Comment: this is a simple example i have multiple select options with different values

Comment: Are you looking to show the div only if one of the options in a particular optgroup are selected?

Comment: exactly now you got me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the if statement you could have a switch that goes through all the different values. Then on the default case would be if the user selects nothing.

```js
function show(that) {
  var value = that.value;

   switch(value){
       case "show1":
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  break;
case "show2":
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  break;
case "show3":
           document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  break;
default:
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<select onchange="show(this);">
    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
    <optgroup label="show div">
    <option value="show1">show 1</option>
    <option value="show2">show 2</option>
    <option value="show3">show 3</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    Hidden Div
</div>
```

Comment: this is a simple example i have multiple select options with different values this code will work for all select options

Comment: I updated my answer so that it would work with all option values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression in your first `if` statement so that it will match any element with value = "show.*", where `.*` matches any character 0 or more times. So the method `test()` will return true for all of your elements with `value="show.*`".

```js
function show(that) {
    if (/show.*/gi.test(that.value)) {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="show(this);">
    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
    <optgroup label="show div">
    <option value="show1">show 1</option>
    <option value="show2">show 2</option>
    <option value="show3">show 3</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    Hidden Div
</div>
```